# Seeking a cleaner way to avoid nested if statements (with sapply)

Tags: r, if-statement, sapply

I have 2 data frames

```
lookup_table <- data.frame(Country = c("UK","France", "Germany"), A = c(0,0,1), B = c(1,6,7), C = c(4,8,9))
set.seed(123) # for being reproducible
df <-  data.frame(Country = c("UK","UK","France","France","Germany","Germany","Germany","France","UK"), Values =  runif(9, 1, 10))
```

I would like to have a 3rd column in df which assigns class based on the values in column 2, AND on the country.

Something like the below, but the values should not be fixed: they should depend on the values & country in the lookup table

```
Class <- function(x) { 
  if(x > 0 & x <= 1) y <- "A"
  if(x > 1 & x <= 4) y <- "B"
  if(x > 4) y <- "C"
  return(y)
}

df$Class <- sapply(df$Values,Class)
```

Thanks in advance for any help

Comment: It depends on the values - which are randomized in the example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

And here is the `dplyr` solution.

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  inner_join(lookup_table, by = "Country") %>%
  mutate(Class = ifelse(Values > A & Values < B, "A", 
                 ifelse(Values > B & Values < C, "B", 
                 ifelse(Values > C, "C", "Not_found"))))
```

Add `select(-c(A,B,C))` at the end of the pipe for a cleaner output `data.frame`. As an added benefit of this approach, any values that don't fall in range will get flagged as `"Not_found"`.

Answer (score 1):

We can do a `join` between the 'lookup_table' and 'df' `on` the 'Country', `melt` it to 'long' format.  As @zx8754 commented, use the `cut` function grouped by 'Country' (or `findInterval` to get the numeric index, use that to get the corresponding 'variable', assign it as 'newVar'

```
library(data.table)
d1 <- melt(setDT(lookup_table)[df, on = "Country"], id.var = c("Country", "Values"))[,
          newVar:=unique(variable)[findInterval(Values, unique(value))], Country]
```

Subset the columns of interest and get the `unique` values

```
unique(d1[, c("Country", "Values", "newVar"), with = FALSE])
#   Country   Values newVar
#1:      UK 3.588198      B
#2:      UK 8.094746      C
#3:  France 4.680792      A
#4:  France 8.947157      C
#5: Germany 9.464206      C
#6: Germany 1.410008      A
#7: Germany 5.752949      A
#8:  France 9.031771      C
#9:      UK 5.962915      C
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option:

```
df <- merge(df, lookup_table, by='Country', all.x=T)

df$Class <- 'A'                         # default
df$Class <- with(df, replace(Class, Values > B & Values <= C, 'B'))
df$Class <- with(df, replace(Class, Values > C, 'C'))
df
#  Country   Values A B C Class
#1  France 2.371120 0 6 8     A
#2  France 6.155804 0 6 8     B
#3  France 5.635268 0 6 8     A
#4 Germany 9.661230 1 7 9     C
#5 Germany 6.412292 1 7 9     A
#6 Germany 3.148534 1 7 9     A
#7      UK 4.661493 0 1 4     C
#8      UK 6.933073 0 1 4     C
#9      UK 4.623160 0 1 4     C
```

You can remove any unwanted columns from the result.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the result with base R:

```
dfa<-merge(lookup_table,df)
Class <- function(x) { 
  if(x[5] > x[2] & x[5] <= x[3]) y <- "A"
  if(x[5] > x[3] & x[5] <= x[4]) y <- "B"
  if(x[5] > x[4]) y <- "C"
  return(y)
}
dfa$Class <- sapply(1:nrow(dfa),function(ri)Class(dfa[ri,]))
dfa[,-c(2:4)]

> dfa[,-c(2:4)]
  Country   Values Class
1  France 4.680792     A
2  France 8.947157     C
3  France 9.031771     C
4 Germany 1.410008     A
5 Germany 5.752949     A
6 Germany 9.464206     C
7      UK 3.588198     B
8      UK 8.094746     C
9      UK 5.962915     C
```

Answer (score 0):

If you change the form of your `lookup_table` specifying the intervals already, then this task can be easily performed using `non-equi` joins from the development version of data.table, v1.9.7 ([Installation instructions](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/wiki/Installation)):

```
require(data.table) #v1.9.7+
setDT(df)[lookup, Class := i.Class, on = .(Country, Values > value1, Values <= value2)]
#    Country   Values Class
# 1:      UK 3.588198     B
# 2:      UK 8.094746     C
# 3:  France 4.680792     A
# 4:  France 8.947157     C
# 5: Germany 9.464206     C
# 6: Germany 1.410008     A
# 7: Germany 5.752949     A
# 8:  France 9.031771     C
# 9:      UK 5.962915     C

## i.Class refers to Class from i argument = lookup$Class
```

where `lookup` is constructed from `lookup_table` as follows:

```
setDT(lookup_table)[, D := Inf]
lookup = lookup_table[, .(Country, 
                          Class = rep(c("A", "B", "C"), each=.N), 
                          value1 = c(A, B, C), 
                          value2 = c(B, C, D))]
#    Country Class value1 value2
# 1:      UK     A      0      1
# 2:  France     A      0      6
# 3: Germany     A      1      7
# 4:      UK     B      1      4
# 5:  France     B      6      8
# 6: Germany     B      7      9
# 7:      UK     C      4    Inf
# 8:  France     C      8    Inf
# 9: Germany     C      9    Inf
```